# Can't find php binaries after successfull installation

Tags: apt, software-installation, php

For various reasons I'm trying to reinstall PHP. I removed it with `apt-get purge php`, and added it again with `apt-get install php`. However, something funny is happening, in that it *is* installed but is unusable, and I don't know where it installed to either. When I run `php -v` I just see:

```
The program 'php' can be found in the following packages:
 * php7.0-cli
 * hhvm
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

and `whereis php` outputs `php: /usr/share/php7.0-mcrypt /usr/share/php7.0-mysql /usr/share/php7.0-json /usr/share/php7.0-readline /usr/share/php7.0-curl /usr/share/php7.0-mbstring /usr/share/php /usr/share/php7.0-gd /usr/share/php7.0-common /usr/share/php7.0-opcache /usr/share/php7.0-xml /usr/share/php7.0-zip /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz`, none of which are the actual PHP executable.

However if I run `apt-get install php` again then I get told `php is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6)`, so it is installed *somewhere*.

I haven't knowingly changed my $PATH variable, which I read could cause this, but here it is anyway: `/home/myname/bin:/home/myname/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`.

I'm on 16.04.

Comment: Output of `which php` also `dpkg -L php` please.

Comment: `which php` gives no output, `dpkg -L php` gives `/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/php
/usr/share/doc/php/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/copyright`

Answer (score 0):

The `php` it self is a meta package which pulls other necessary packages and installs them on your system.

For now you are playing with the meta package and it does not have any effect on your system, to get a running PHP, you have to install `php7.0` which installs:

- php7.0-common (documentation, examples and common module for PHP)

And most likly one of these three depends on how you want to interact with your PHP,

- php7.0-fpm (FPM-CGI binary)
- libapache2-mod-php7.0 (Apache 2 module)
- php7.0-cgi (CGI binary)

you can even install `php7.0-cli` to only get a PHP command line.

Comment: Are you sure? On the initial install it was enough to install just `php`. Why when reinstalling would the process be different? Anyhow, I'll try this when I get the chance.